# NextJS does not recognize dynamically added static assets in production

Tags: node.js, next.js

I'm running a two container docker setup; NextJS for the public facing web, and Django backend for admins to add content. The routes are nicely working with `getInitialProps` which fetches the added content. As the content references static images, they are connected via docker volumes (`./static/media` on django container and `./public/media` on nextjs container).

However when a new image appears in `./public/media`, the started NextJs server returns a 404 response for those images.

// EDITED SOLUTION: As suggested by @Pierfrancesco

The workaround solution is to create a custom server which dynamically serves those files

```js
// server.js
const express = require('express')
const next = require('next')

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()

  server.get('/media/images/*', (req, res) => {
    // Disallow travelling up in the file tree
    let target = req.originalUrl.replace("..", "")
    return res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public' + target);
  })

  server.all('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })
})
```

Could this be a feature request or is this a bug in NextJS?

Comment: Just to share a starting idea, if you use a dynamic route to fetch those images?

Comment: It's called "static" for a reason. Don't put dynamic content in what's supposed to be a static folder. You wouldn't want to anyway because this won't scale well. Next.js is likely memcaching everything in your static directory to be able to serve without accessing the file system for each request, and if you have dynamic content in there, your Node.js memory usage will likely skyrocket.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts It's not called "static" but "public". Where is it written that the folder is supposed to be static? And I don't necessarily agree. Of course for a site with thousands of users it would not be sufficient, but for a simple CMS, f.i. imagine running a blog and having to restart your site after every post.

Comment: @Nightowl did you find a solution for this? I'm running into the same issue

Answer (score 0):

"Only assets that are in the public directory at build time will be served by Next.js. Files added at request time won't be available. We recommend using a third-party service like AWS S3 for persistent file storage." See [Next.js Static Assets](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/static-assets)